# How would I get psycopg2 logging of query execution time?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to get the performance statistics on queries executed by psycopg2, but the documentation / examples still seem fuzzy and not as clear as it could be.

I've at least got debugging working through the logger.
What would I need to do to access the performance data for the query? I'm wanting to get the number for query execution time.

Is there a method I can access, or something else I need to initialize to output the query execution time?

Here's a pieced together extract of what I have so far:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions
from psycopg2.extras import LoggingConnection
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# set higher up in script
db_settings = {
    "user": user,
    "password": password,
    "host": host,
    "database": dbname,
}

query_txt = "[query_txt_from file]"

conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_factory=LoggingConnection, **db_settings)
conn.initialize(logger)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query_txt)
```

and I get

```
DEBUG:__main__: [the query executed]
```

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't collect and report the server-side query execution time, sans client latency and data transfer time. So psycopg2 can't report it. psycopg2 could collect the time taken between requesting query execution and getting the first result. I don't know if it does. What query execution time do you want, exactly? Total time from sending query to getting first result? to last result? just server-side execution?

Comment: server side execution; as close to \timing as I can get; perhaps I'll have to access the log feature through sys console output  "log_min_duration_statement = 0 in the configuration, then SET client_min_messages = log"; or see if I can access a feature like EXPLAIN that also has the execution time.

Comment: `\timing` in psql is full time including network latency and reault transfer time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy enough to set timestamp at start of execution and calculate duration at end. You'll need your own simple subclasses of LoggingConnection and LoggingCursor. See my example code.

This is based on source of MinTimeLoggingConnection you can find in `psycopg2/extras.py` source.

```
import time
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions
from psycopg2.extras import LoggingConnection, LoggingCursor
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# MyLoggingCursor simply sets self.timestamp at start of each query                                                                 
class MyLoggingCursor(LoggingCursor):
    def execute(self, query, vars=None):
        self.timestamp = time.time()
        return super(MyLoggingCursor, self).execute(query, vars)

    def callproc(self, procname, vars=None):
        self.timestamp = time.time()
        return super(MyLoggingCursor, self).callproc(procname, vars)

# MyLogging Connection:                                                                                                             
#   a) calls MyLoggingCursor rather than the default                                                                                
#   b) adds resulting execution (+ transport) time via filter()                                                                     
class MyLoggingConnection(LoggingConnection):
    def filter(self, msg, curs):
        return msg + "   %d ms" % int((time.time() - curs.timestamp) * 1000)

    def cursor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('cursor_factory', MyLoggingCursor)
        return LoggingConnection.cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)

db_settings = {
    ....
}

query_txt = "[query_text_from file]"

conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_factory=MyLoggingConnection, **db_settings)
conn.initialize(logger)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query_text)
```

and you'll get:

```
DEBUG: __main__:[query]     3 ms
```

within your `filter()` you can change the formatting, or choose to not display, if less than some value.

Comment: In python 3 you need to replace the `filter` code with `return msg.decode(psycopg2.extensions.encodings[self.encoding], 'replace') + "   %d ms" % int((time.time() - curs.timestamp) * 1000)` to avoid `TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`