# Measure query execution time in Psycopg2

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 for python and I want to track the database execution time.

```
starttime = time.time()
cursor.execute(sql_statement, args)
print(time.time() - starttime)
```

Does the `cursor.execute()` function return after the sql is executed or immediately?

If so how do I keep track of the sql query time?

Comment: `execute` will will only return after the server response. But your sample code will include the time it takes to transfer the data from the server to the client.

Comment: here this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661495/how-would-i-get-psycopg2-logging-of-query-execution-time