# How to get execution time of postgres cursor (python)

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to get the execution time of my cursor after getting the results, Basically needs to execute the queries in postgres sql and logging the time taken to execute the query at postgres sql server's end in my logs.

Trying to achieve somrthing like this:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="shrek", user="postgres", password="apple")
print(conn)
cur = conn.cursor()
abc =cur.execute('select id from company')
result = cur.fetchone()
print(result[0])
print(cur.fetchtime())-------> i want to print the execution time
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661495/how-would-i-get-psycopg2-logging-of-query-execution-time

Comment: got error -----> AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute 'initialize'

Comment: tried to install logging got below error: Shrikants-MBP:js shrek$ pip install logging


      File "/Users/shrek/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib2to3/refactor.py", line 18, in <module>
        import logging
ij1tfsc0/logging/logging/__init__.py", line 618
        raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.